# Petsc Mex file crashes

Tags: matlab, petsc

I have a working code that solves a certain problem by using KSPSolve from Petsc (using gmres solver with ilu pre-conditioner).
I wanted to call this code from MATLAB so I coded a mex-file.
However, KSPSolve is crashing my mex file and MATLAB when it is called.

I used valgrind and it seems that the first error is in some sse2 code.
If I remove the call to KSPSolve everything works fine. If I call the whole code outside MATLAB, it also works.

Anyone knows of possible compatibility issues between Petsc and MATLAB? Can this be resolved?
Thanks,